# QuickSelect - Print k smallest elements of array A of size n in O(n) time and O(5k) auxiliary space - read only once

Tags: algorithm, select, data-structures, time-complexity, quicksort

I've been trying to solve this problem:

> The `Select` algorithm allows us to find in a given array `A` the value of the `i`th index in linear time (`O(n)`), but requires us to keep `A` in memory throughout the entire algorithm.
>
> Suggest an algorithm which receives an array of size `n`, named `A`, which contains natural numbers, and prints the `k` smallest elements of `A` with the following restrictions:
>
> For each `i=1...n`, you are only allowed to read the value `A[i]` once. You are not allowed to write into, or exchange between elements of `A`.
>
> You are allowed to use a second array of size `5k`, named `B`, which can be written and read without restrictions.
>
> Run-time must be linear, by size of `A`. Assume `k<n`, and that `5k<n`.

I realized that I need to utilize a Median of Medians approach, but I'm having a hard time thinking about how the pivot would be calculated, as I an only store `5k` elements.

This would mean that I cannot calculate the Median of Medians which would make the best 70% 30% pivot choice, and won't reach a linear run-time.

I would appreciate any input in the matter.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Start copying from A into an auxiliary array.  Whenever you collect 2k elements, use quickselect to keep the smallest k elements and discard the rest.

Finally call quickselect once more to discard all but the smallest k elements in the remainder.

Comment: Why not copy 5k elements to the auxiliary array before calling Quickselect? Might as well use the whole 5k auxiliary array size.

Comment: Just to make it clear that you don't need 5k slots.

Comment: My guess is the 5k elements is tied to something like [median of medians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians) in order to keep worst case time complexity at O(n), otherwise worst case is O(n^2).

Comment: @rcgldr no, quickselect with median of medians is O(n), and so is this.  5k is definitely faster, because the first pivot is always sufficient, but it doesn't change the complexity.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. I would just like to say, that your way of approaching this problem doesn't seem to result in a linear run time, O(n), as for each 5k elements, we pick the smallest k elements using QuickSelect. That means calling QuickSelect k times, that would be O(k^2), and you do that for n/k times, so overall you'd have O(k*n). Does that really come up to linear time?

Comment: @EatayMizrachi  QuickSelect runs n/k times, and O(k) * n/k = O(n)